# Add run id when registering ml.azure model via python (pipeline)

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have registed a model in this way:

```
from azureml.core.model import Model
model = Model.register(model_path="sklearn_regression_model.pkl",
                      model_name="sklearn_regression_model",
                      tags={'area': "diabetes", 'type': "regression"},
                      description="Ridge regression model to predict diabetes",
                      workspace=ws)
```

However I would like to add run id, from the experiment, so I can always back-track the model to the experiment that created the model. In azure ml there is a column indicating that it is possible to add run id to a registered model, however the model class doesn't have this parameter.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing, I would assume this would be automatic but it seems it's not.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see the `Experiment name` and the `Run ID` in the Azure Machine Learning Studio, I had to use `Run.register_model()` in the outer pipeline file instead.

It is in some way even better since at that place we get access to the `Dataset` objects which we can link to the model.

```py
run = Experiment(workspace, "rgb_finetune").submit(pipeline)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)

eval_metrics = run.get_metrics()["Fine-Tuned Evaluation"]
if eval_metrics["AP50"] > 0.5:
    run.find_step_run("finetune.py")[0].register_model(
        model_name="92c5e1a1d1",
        model_path="outputs/model_export",
        properties={"AP50": round(float(eval_metrics["AP50"]), 3)},
        description="RGB model",
        datasets=[("images", images), ("labels", labels)],
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the [Model Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py) has a "Run ID", which you can verify with:

`azureml.core.Model.run_id` this contains the ID of the Run that created the Model.

The `run_id` is an optional ID used to filter returned results.

So, you if you register it first, you should be able to query the `run_id`.

**Alternatively**, you can query the `run_id` from the `Run` that generated your model, and then you can register using a tag as `tags={'run_id': '{your-run-id}'}`

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer the question. The question is about registering a model not querying.

Comment: Hi, my point is that if you register it first, you should be able to query the `run_id` afterwards. Please verify this. If you really must register the `run_id` at first, you can pass a `tag` parameter as a workaround

Comment: Hi @Francois, I've edited my answer to try to explain better that the `run_id` is a parameter inside the `Model` Class. So when you register it, it is already contained within the object `Model` itself. Also added an alternative suggestion.